Does HOSVD not work with complex numbers?
The output of
result = 
  ResourceFunction[
    "TuckerDecomposition"][{{{I, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}];
Grid[{{"Core Tensor:", MatrixForm[result[[1]]]}, {"Factor Matrices:", 
   TableForm[result[[2]]]}}, Alignment -> Left, Frame -> All]
result[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]] Conjugate[result[[1]][[2]][[1]][[1]]] + 
 result[[1]][[1]][[2]][[1]] Conjugate[result[[1]][[2]][[2]][[1]]] + 
 result[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]] Conjugate[result[[1]][[2]][[1]][[2]]] + 
 result[[1]][[1]][[2]][[2]] Conjugate[result[[1]][[2]][[2]][[2]]]

is

which is not correct as the value returned by the last line is supposed to be 0 by the definition of HOSVD where

The last line of code computes the scalar product of S_i_1 = 1 and S_i_1 = 2 and in the complex example, it is not 0. Thus it is not correct. An example of this working correctly with real numbers is below

Is this something wrong with mathematica?

You are more likely to get help if you supply code that can be pasted into Mathematica.  It would be helpful to demonstrate how you multiply the core tensors to get the right answer (with real input) and the "wrong" answer with complex numbers.

@mikado I have updated my question to have the code that one can copy and the testing of a property that is supposed to be satisfied by HOSVD. Along with a demonstration of it working for real numbers.
